# Connect to android 7 with adb over WIFI without ever connecting via USB

Tags: adb, adbwireless

I want to connect to an android phone using adb over WIFI. When I do (either by using [WIFI Adb](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ttxapps.wifiadb&hl=en) or the buildin ADB over Network in android) I get:

```
$ adb connect 192.168.122.203
failed to authenticate to 192.168.122.203:5555
```

and adb devices shows the same result:

```
List of devices attached
192.168.122.203:5555    unauthorized
```

The solution I find everywhere is: Connect the device via USB and authorize the PC, then connect via WIFI.

Unfortunately I cannot do that, because:

I have installed android-x86 (newest version is android 7.1.2) inside libvrt-manager (KVM).
I have no Idea how I would connect this virtual machine with android via USB to my PC.

So is there a way to authorize a PC for adb usage without every connecting the android Device via USB?

Answer (score 0):

True wireless adb is available only on Android version 11 and above. All version below you have to connect the USB cable and forward the tcp/ip port 5555 and then connect this is called adb over WiFi.
More details are [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#connect-to-a-device-over-wi-fi-android-11+)

I would recommend using a Android 11 emulator if possible if you can't have a USB connection